# Apply filters to photos in Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, filter, appcelerator

I am building an iOS app in Appcelerator and I need to let the user take pictures and then apply a filter to them (like Instagram). How can I achieve this? Is it perhaps possible to use any javascript based image filter library?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible, http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/ you can see some filters here as an example. All of these affects are achieved by looping over the image data and manipulating the pixels one by one. Hard part here would be making(or finding) the algorithms that would look good, like instagram has.

There are also masks in instagram, which are images like a polariod or old films, like here: http://www.aviary.com/tutorial.aspx?tutorial=cross_processing&step=12 . These are applied using clipping masks : https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_2_canvas_clipping.html or merging two images data, like here: http://www.benbarnett.net/2011/06/02/using-html5-canvas-for-image-masks/ .

So all of what instagram does with images, you can do with canvas. It would be cpu intensive on a phone, but i think iPhone can handle it.

Some examples:

- https://github.com/pnitsch/BitmapData.js
- http://mezzoblue.github.com/PaintbrushJS/demo/

Comment: Since you are using Appcelerator, I described methods to do this in web technologies. Of couse appliying these filters 'natively' would perform much better.

Comment: this is the best answer but it's very very very slow if you're doing it to photos, they're too big...

Answer (score 3):

you might want to take a look at this API.

http://developers.aviary.com/effects-api

I started with it a few months ago when it wasn't quite yet there, but I here they have made additional progress