# change photo colors / apply photo filters titanium mobile

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

is it possible to change image colors in titanium-mobile? or apply filters on it?

i'd like to make my pictures more red...

so far I haven't found anything in the framework api that suggest it's possible..

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Titanium by default doesn't have a filter class, but using some
>   javascript libraries u can achieve this, there is all ready one post
>   based on this on stack over flow, [click here to see the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220213/apply-filters-to-photos-in-appcelerator)